# PHP - Solving Equations that include a ternary operator without eval()?

Tags: php, eval, equations

I'm currently working on a PHP application that needs to solve equations that may, or may not, have a ternary operator.

For example, after replacing my variables in the equation, we are left with the following string:

`$eq = '(3.07 > 10 ? 1.93 * 10 : 3.07 * 1.93)';`

We were previously using eval() (which would obviously work), but moved to an EOS package from PHP Classes (https://www.phpclasses.org/package/2055-PHP-Solve-equations-with-multiple-variables.html) because of the security issues with eval().

The EOS class doesn't interpret the ternary operator, and I don't want to go back to eval(), so what are my options here? Is there a better PHP EOS library that I can use somewhere?

Comment: Well ternary isn't something mathematical. It's just used in programming as far as I know. You'll probably need to make your own parser to make the math.

Comment: I'd prefer not to build my own parser, if I can avoid it. My buddy told me about ast.literal_eval() in Python, which sounded promising, but there doesn't seem to be a PHP equivalent, which is very disappointing. @Don'tPanic The parser doesn't require the surrounding (). I just happened to enter the equation into the DB with the surrounding (). Why?

Comment: I was just wondering if I should trim them off for my answer. But I decided to just answer it without them.

Comment: Also, if you've found something in Python that could do the job, but your main project is in PHP, it's possible for PHP to pass the expression to Python to evaluate it.

Comment: @Nate, "ternary" operations/if structures won't work with ast.literal_eval either.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's just one ternary, you could break up the string into the separate parts of the ternary expression and evaluate the parts separately.

```
$eq = '3.07 > 10 ? 1.93 * 10 : 3.07 * 1.93';

preg_match('/(.+)\?(.+):(.+)/', $eq, $parts);

if (isset($parts[3])) {
  $result = Parser::solve($parts[1]) ? Parser::solve($parts[2]) : Parser::solve($parts[3]);
} else {
  $result = Parser::solve($eq);
}
```

If there's more than one ternary, you could probably still could do it if you were better at regex than me. :)

I admit this approach is a bit naive, I can think of various things that would break it pretty easily, e.g. a parenthetical ternary sub-expression, but it could work for simple examples like the one in your question.

Comment: Yea, I definitely appreciate the help, but this is far too limited to work for my application.

Comment: Understandable. Well, good luck with it! I may update this later if I think of something better.